# Which all fortify versions support .net2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

Could you please help in figuring out the versions supported by Fortify for .net2010 Windows 32 bit as well as 64.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In response to a related question, Fortify Tech Support sent me HP Fortify Secure Coding Rulepacks Supported Libraries Version 2014.3.0.0009. On page 53 it states:

> Microsoft ASP.NET MVC coverage includes identifying untrusted input from web  controller methods and standard ASP.NET MVC web interfaces. Sources of untrusted input include cookies, requests, URLs, http headers, system properties, file   system, database, and network sources.

I received this document from Fortify and Google did not find it on their web site.  However they also recommended [A Taxonomy of Coding Errors that Affect Security](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/index.html) which covers C#/VB.NET/ASP.NET

Fortify runs as a native application in both Win 32 and 64 bit platforms, although my experience is on the 64 bit as the performance would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the versions of Fortify SCA whose secure coding plugins support VS 2010 - then as far back as at least SCA 3.4 up through 4.21.

Starting with 4.21, SCA and Tools only ships with 64bit windows installers.  I think you may be able to contact fortify support for SCA 4.21 32bit tools.

As for the future?  If we look back, Visual Studio 2008 plugins stopped being available about 18 months after mainstream support for visual studio 2008 from Microsoft expired. I'd guess you have a few years until the VS2010 plugins are pulled from SCA.  (Even then, you can probably do some partial uninstall/install magic and retain some level of functionality in future versions of SCA.)